# Help with JQuery and passing variables into a show/hide function

Tags: jquery, variables, hide, show, slide

I have a simple show/hide jquery script that works fine on its own, The problem is that I am using it on the comments section off a php/mysql driven site.

I am struggling to pass the commment id variable to the jquery script so that the show/hide function works for each comment independently.

I am new to jquery and javascript, so thanks in advance for your explanations.

Javacript

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('p.1').hide();    
    $('a.1').click(function(){

        $('a#read_more').hide(1700);
        $('p.1').slideDown(1500);   

        $('a#read_less').click(function(){

            $('p.1').slideUp(1500);
            $('a#read_more').show(1700);    

        });

    });         
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="1" id="read_more">Read More</a>
<p class="1" id="1">
LOREM IPSUM DOLOR SIT AMET, CONSECTETUER ADIPISCING ELIT, SED DIAM NONUMMY NIBH      UISMOD TINCIDUNT UT LAOREET DOLORE MAGNA ALIQUAM ERAT VOLUTPAT. UT WISI ENIM AD MINIM VENIAM, QUIS NOSTRUD EXERCI TATION ULLAMCORPER SUSCIPIT LOBORTIS NISL UT ALIQUIP EX EA COMMODO CONSEQUAT. DUIS AUTEM VEL EUM IRIURE DOLOR IN HENDRERIT IN VULPUTATE VELIT ESSE MOLESTIE CONSEQUAT, VEL ILLUM DOLORE EU FEUGIAT .<br />
    <a href="#" class="1" id="read_less">Read Less</a>
    </p>
```

Comment: looks like you will end up with multiple `<p>`s with the same id... is this correct?

Comment: could you provide two comments instead of just one... would help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kXfr9/) work? It doesn't get the `id` of the comment, but it specifically targets each comment individually.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('li.comment p.cText').hide();    
    $('li.comment a.read_more').click(function(){

        $(this).hide(1700);
        $(this).next("p").slideDown(1500);   

        $('li.comment a.read_less').click(function(){

            $(this).parent("p").slideUp(1500);
            $(this).parent("p").prev("a").show(1700);    

        });

    });         
});
```

Comment: Thanks it works great.  I don't understant the code much but it works so thanks!

Comment: I've set your functions to only target the `li` that each part is contained within so that way it won't spread to all the other `.read_less/more` bits, and so that only that specific `p` is shown/hidden.